# Knockout bind 2 links to different views and swich modelview

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, view

I'm new to knockout and want to have 2 links on the page with 2 models.  I would like the click event on the links switch which view model gets displayed.  I've tried a few ways and have a jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/edgrttj3/7/ but I can't get it to work.  Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

```
<div id="content">

    <a id="button1" href="#" >View 1</a>&nbsp;
    <a id="button2" href="#" >View 2</a>&nbsp;
    <hr />

    <div data-bind="with: selectedView">
        <div data-bind="template: { name: templateName, data: data }"></div>
    </div>

    <script id="oneTmpl" type="text/html">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
                <input data-bind="value: name" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <script id="twoTmpl" type="text/html">
        First:
        <input data-bind="value: firstName" />
        Last:
        <input data-bind="value: lastName" />
    </script>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var View = function (title, templateName, data) {
    this.title = title;
    this.templateName = templateName;
    this.data = data;
};

var subModelA = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { id: 1, name: "one" },
        { id: 2, name: "two" },
        { id: 3, name: "three" }
    ])
};

var subModelB = {
    firstName: ko.observable("Bob"),
    lastName: ko.observable("Smith")
};


var viewModel = {
    views: ko.observableArray([
        new View("one", "oneTmpl", subModelA),
        new View("two", "twoTmpl", subModelB)
    ]),
    selectedView: ko.observable()
};

function setSelectedView(newview) {
    alert(newview);
    if (newview == "oneTmpl") {
        viewModel.selectedView = viewModel.views[0];
    } else {
        viewModel.selectedView = viewModel.views[1];
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        document.getElementById ("button1").addEventListener("click", setSelectedView('oneTmpl'), false);
        document.getElementById ("button1").addEventListener("click", setSelectedView('twoTmpl'), false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your implementation is almost there. There are just couple of tweaks you need to do.

- selectedView from the ViewModel is an observable object. An observable object is basically a function. In order to modify the value of that object you need to pass the new value as an argument `selectedView(valueIsHere)`.
- views from the ViewModel is an observable array object. The same like above, as an observable object is a function to get its value for a specific index you need to call it like a function first followed with its index `views()[0]`

So here is how it looks after the update:

```
var View = function (title, templateName, data) {
  this.title = title;
  this.templateName = templateName;
  this.data = data;
};

var subModelA = {
  items: ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, name: "one" },
    { id: 2, name: "two" },
    { id: 3, name: "three" }
  ])
};

var subModelB = {
  firstName: ko.observable("Bob"),
  lastName: ko.observable("Smith")
};


var ViewModel =  function (){
  this.views = ko.observableArray([
    new View("one", "oneTmpl", subModelA),
    new View("two", "twoTmpl", subModelB)
  ]);
  this.selectedView = ko.observable();
  this.select = function(id){
    if (id === 1) {
        this.selectedView(this.views()[0]);
    } else {
        this.selectedView(this.views()[1]);
    }
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And here are few changes to the button:

```
<a id="button1" href="#" data-bind="click: select(1)">View 1</a>&nbsp;
<a id="button2" href="#" data-bind="click: select(2)">View 2</a>&nbsp;
```

Comment: bootstrap sound good but eventually I want to expand on it and place the views in different html files and understand how this can be done with knockout on a larger set of views and change the displayed view with links and set the model data with knockout bindings.

Comment: @KH1229 I changed the solution :)